# Why Terraform wants to recreate the resource if no "forces replacement" change appears?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-iot-hub, terraform-provider-azure

I have an IoT Hub on Azure which cannot be deleted. However, starting yesterday, I cannot update the endpoints without recreating the whole IoT Hub. However, Terraform doesn't show me exactly why it needs to recreate it. I've tried using TF_LOG=TRACE but I couldn't find anything useful.

Here is the section of the tf file for the IoT Hub:

```
resource "azurerm_iothub" "iothubhgu" {
  name                = "perf8f17c3iothubhaac"
  resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  location            = "northeurope"

  sku {
    name     = "S3"
    capacity = "10"
  }

  event_hub_partition_count = 128
  event_hub_retention_in_days = 1

  endpoint {
    type                       = "AzureIotHub.StorageContainer"
    connection_string          = azurerm_storage_account.datalakehgu.primary_blob_connection_string
    name                       = "device-twin-changes"
    resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
    batch_frequency_in_seconds = 300
    max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = 134217728
    container_name             = azurerm_storage_container.device_twin_changes.name
    encoding                   = "json"
    file_name_format           = "year={YYYY}/month={MM}/day={DD}/hour={HH}/{iothub}-{partition}-{mm}"
  }

   endpoint {
    type                       = "AzureIotHub.StorageContainer"
    connection_string          = azurerm_storage_account.datalakehgu.primary_blob_connection_string
    name                       = "telemetry"
    resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
    batch_frequency_in_seconds = 300
    max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = 134217728
    container_name             = azurerm_storage_container.telemetry.name
    encoding                   = "json"
    file_name_format           = "year={YYYY}/month={MM}/day={DD}/hour={HH}/{iothub}-{partition}-{mm}"
  }

  # Endpoint for device telemetry to ingest
  endpoint {
    type                = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
    connection_string   = azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule.iothub_ingestion_send.primary_connection_string
    name                = "device-telemetry-to-ingest"
    resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  }

  # Endpoint for all telemetry
  endpoint {
    type                = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
    connection_string   = azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule.iothub_all_ingestion_send.primary_connection_string
    name                = "all-telemetry"
    resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  }

  # Endpoint for device telemetry to enrich
  endpoint {
    type                = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
    connection_string   = azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule.eventhubauthorizationrulehgu.primary_connection_string
    name                = "device-telemetry-to-enrich"
    resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  }

  # Endpoint for ONT ID changes detection
  endpoint {
    type                = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
    connection_string   = azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule.ont_send.primary_connection_string
    name                = "device-ont-changes"
    resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  }

## All endpoint for device twin changes IoTHub
  endpoint {
    type                = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
    connection_string   = azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule.iothub_send.primary_connection_string
    name                = "all-device-twin-changes"
    resource_group_name = "perf-northeurope"
  }

  route {
    name           = "device-twin-changes"
    source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
    condition      = "true"
    endpoint_names = ["device-twin-changes"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  route {
    name           = "telemetry"
    source         = "DeviceMessages"
    condition      = "true"
    endpoint_names = ["telemetry"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  # Enrich based on telemetry route
  route {
    name           = "device-telemetry-to-enrich"
    source         = "DeviceMessages"
    condition      = "IS_DEFINED($body.Datablock_id.Device_Info[0].SYSINF_UPT_NUM) AND (NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.shouldAttemptEnrich) OR ($twin.tags.shouldAttemptEnrich = true AND(NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.enrichNextAttemptDate) OR $body.Timestamp_Report > $twin.tags.enrichNextAttemptDate)))"
    endpoint_names = ["device-telemetry-to-enrich"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  # Route for ONT ID changes detection
  route {
    name           = "device-ont-changes"
    source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
    condition      = "IS_DEFINED($body.properties.reported.Datablock_id.Device_Info.PLOAM_PWD_DES) AND (NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.PLOAM_PWD) OR $twin.tags.PLOAM_PWD != $body.properties.reported.Datablock_id.Device_Info.PLOAM_PWD_DES)"
    endpoint_names = ["device-ont-changes"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  # Route for device telemetry to ingest
  route {
    name           = "device-telemetry-to-ingest"
    source         = "DeviceMessages"
    condition      = "IS_ARRAY($body.Datablock_id.Stations_OnDemand)"
    endpoint_names = ["device-telemetry-to-ingest"]
    enabled        = true
  }

 # All routes
  route {
    name           = "all-telemetry"
    source         = "DeviceMessages"
    condition      = "true"
    endpoint_names = ["all-telemetry"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  route {
    name           = "all-device-twin-changes"
    source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
    condition      = "true"
    endpoint_names = ["all-device-twin-changes"]
    enabled        = true
  }

  # Enrich messages
  enrichment {
    key            = "iotHubName"
    value          = "$iothubname"
    endpoint_names = ["device-telemetry-to-enrich", "all-device-twin-changes", "device-ont-changes"]
  }


  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [timeouts, shared_access_policy, tags]
  }

  tags = "${merge(map("allocatable_enrollment", "no"), local.tags)}"
}
```

And the plan shows the following:

```
  # azurerm_iothub.iothubhgu must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_iothub" "iothubhgu" {
      ~ endpoint                      = [
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = 300
              + connection_string          = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;BlobEndpoint=https://perf8f17c3datalakehaac.blob.core.windows.net/;AccountName=perf8f17c3datalakehaac;AccountKey=1um8iIPDuJwqzKuV160KjkK+GDiRWOS+MN8CL2O74OdARxGNKp7MziZFdgAAGZ7R95K7aDIfBHHCLbhQg4kY+g=="
              + container_name             = "device-twin-changes"
              + encoding                   = "json"
              + file_name_format           = "year={YYYY}/month={MM}/day={DD}/hour={HH}/{iothub}-{partition}-{mm}"
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = 134217728
              + name                       = "device-twin-changes"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.StorageContainer"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = 300
              + connection_string          = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;BlobEndpoint=https://perf8f17c3datalakehaac.blob.core.windows.net/;AccountName=perf8f17c3datalakehaac;AccountKey=1um8iIPDuJwqzKuV160KjkK+GDiRWOS+MN8CL2O74OdARxGNKp7MziZFdgAAGZ7R95K7aDIfBHHCLbhQg4kY+g=="
              + container_name             = "telemetry"
              + encoding                   = "json"
              + file_name_format           = "year={YYYY}/month={MM}/day={DD}/hour={HH}/{iothub}-{partition}-{mm}"
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = 134217728
              + name                       = "telemetry"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.StorageContainer"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = null
              + connection_string          = (known after apply)
              + container_name             = null
              + encoding                   = null
              + file_name_format           = null
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = null
              + name                       = "device-telemetry-to-ingest"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = null
              + connection_string          = "Endpoint=sb://perf8f17c3agenthaac.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=perfiothub;SharedAccessKey=EULTnpJs0o2KiT4q3n3kPXs284SfmrOEKcMebbW33no=;EntityPath=all-telemetry"
              + container_name             = null
              + encoding                   = null
              + file_name_format           = null
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = null
              + name                       = "all-telemetry"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = null
              + connection_string          = "Endpoint=sb://perf8f17c3agenthaac.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=perfiothub;SharedAccessKey=OGoxgak3lEDGVgkZm13qG2CWm8+7NLWLelSYZ5V//pM=;EntityPath=device-telemetry-to-enrich"
              + container_name             = null
              + encoding                   = null
              + file_name_format           = null
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = null
              + name                       = "device-telemetry-to-enrich"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = null
              + connection_string          = "Endpoint=sb://perf8f17c3agenthaac.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=perfontsend;SharedAccessKey=JIjJxNvTGf4vyyTDhsKEgOPXEIfnQK44aJTolcWTt9c=;EntityPath=device-ont-changes"
              + container_name             = null
              + encoding                   = null
              + file_name_format           = null
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = null
              + name                       = "device-ont-changes"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
            },
          + {
              + batch_frequency_in_seconds = null
              + connection_string          = "Endpoint=sb://perf8f17c3agenthaac.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=perfiothub;SharedAccessKey=13BmqOHQ8VPUTWp7g03bdVQ6DV3/Fre0IDPWq7oajVk=;EntityPath=all-device-twin-changes"
              + container_name             = null
              + encoding                   = null
              + file_name_format           = null
              + max_chunk_size_in_bytes    = null
              + name                       = "all-device-twin-changes"
              + resource_group_name        = "perf-northeurope"
              + type                       = "AzureIotHub.EventHub"
            },
        ]
      ~ enrichment                    = [
          + {
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "device-telemetry-to-enrich",
                  + "all-device-twin-changes",
                  + "device-ont-changes",
                ]
              + key            = "iotHubName"
              + value          = "$iothubname"
            },
        ]
      ~ event_hub_events_endpoint     = "sb://iothub-ns-perf8f17c3-18825768-541eda30c9.servicebus.windows.net/" -> (known after apply)
      ~ event_hub_events_path         = "perf8f17c3iothubhaac" -> (known after apply)
      + event_hub_operations_endpoint = (known after apply)
      + event_hub_operations_path     = (known after apply)
        event_hub_partition_count     = 128
        event_hub_retention_in_days   = 1
      ~ hostname                      = "perf8f17c3iothubhaac.azure-devices.net" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                            = "/subscriptions/8f17c337-c637-4ce1-8703-1161d680e1e0/resourceGroups/perf-northeurope/providers/Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs/perf8f17c3iothubhaac" -> (known after apply)
        location                      = "northeurope"
        name                          = "perf8f17c3iothubhaac"
        resource_group_name           = "perf-northeurope"
      ~ route                         = [
          + {
              + condition      = "true"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "device-twin-changes",
                ]
              + name           = "device-twin-changes"
              + source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "true"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "telemetry",
                ]
              + name           = "telemetry"
              + source         = "DeviceMessages"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "IS_DEFINED($body.Datablock_id.Device_Info[0].SYSINF_UPT_NUM) AND (NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.shouldAttemptEnrich) OR ($twin.tags.shouldAttemptEnrich = true AND(NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.enrichNextAttemptDate) OR $body.Timestamp_Report > $twin.tags.enrichNextAttemptDate)))"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "device-telemetry-to-enrich",
                ]
              + name           = "device-telemetry-to-enrich"
              + source         = "DeviceMessages"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "IS_DEFINED($body.properties.reported.Datablock_id.Device_Info.PLOAM_PWD_DES) AND (NOT IS_DEFINED($twin.tags.PLOAM_PWD) OR $twin.tags.PLOAM_PWD != $body.properties.reported.Datablock_id.Device_Info.PLOAM_PWD_DES)"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "device-ont-changes",
                ]
              + name           = "device-ont-changes"
              + source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "IS_ARRAY($body.Datablock_id.Stations_OnDemand)"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "device-telemetry-to-ingest",
                ]
              + name           = "device-telemetry-to-ingest"
              + source         = "DeviceMessages"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "true"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "all-telemetry",
                ]
              + name           = "all-telemetry"
              + source         = "DeviceMessages"
            },
          + {
              + condition      = "true"
              + enabled        = true
              + endpoint_names = [
                  + "all-device-twin-changes",
                ]
              + name           = "all-device-twin-changes"
              + source         = "TwinChangeEvents"
            },
        ]
      ~ shared_access_policy          = [
          - {
              - key_name      = "iothubowner"
              - permissions   = "RegistryWrite, ServiceConnect, DeviceConnect"
              - primary_key   = "fEMvmPwxLTUgZOHKYamV+PhoR02veW7RsTvQSNDNjCI="
              - secondary_key = "ohnYydzAXI69oi+wP0otb3N8OLOhXeouP27xgxVHekA="
            },
          - {
              - key_name      = "service"
              - permissions   = "ServiceConnect"
              - primary_key   = "qqIZ2TNVowlrdSyU3VntD4yKsX5jy0DfEJzGETkv59A="
              - secondary_key = "00z0H2h9GTcaSRMrU1o6RWtj/Nvz7Ge20694KHpZrw8="
            },
          - {
              - key_name      = "device"
              - permissions   = "DeviceConnect"
              - primary_key   = "aRCojvERyNCwZZI/PMA4FNKGGd5fweH1wbsOxTO8SAo="
              - secondary_key = "cKtniRudwl1LihoLBDZd2vpWiIthgfqxgz7p59Bnzfw="
            },
          - {
              - key_name      = "registryRead"
              - permissions   = "RegistryRead"
              - primary_key   = "UT7NeK+qensRMGLNo5iIRTX2DENStFObF+mwWRO4U4s="
              - secondary_key = "J3hcMbPHpeEWaFxzleTalxytA7gBKRbb71ikqHxTuI4="
            },
          - {
              - key_name      = "registryReadWrite"
              - permissions   = "RegistryWrite"
              - primary_key   = "S+MXnath3mS9sBjSjU4sJqd0dr7UpG1pA/Q5Bb7lS74="
              - secondary_key = "KojXFtEp9R8K+UA9vIGZn7Dc82L6kLdMJIzGOPqlXzg="
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
        tags                          = {
            "allocatable_enrollment" = "no"
            "environment"            = "perf"
            "maintainer"             = "haac-agent"
            "version"                = "2.3.0-snapshot"
        }
      ~ type                          = "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs" -> (known after apply)

      ~ cloud_to_device {
          ~ default_ttl        = "PT1H" -> (known after apply)
          ~ max_delivery_count = 10 -> (known after apply)

          ~ feedback {
              ~ lock_duration      = "PT1M" -> (known after apply)
              ~ max_delivery_count = 10 -> (known after apply)
              ~ time_to_live       = "PT1H" -> (known after apply)
            }
        }

      ~ fallback_route {
          ~ condition      = "true" -> (known after apply)
          ~ enabled        = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ endpoint_names = [
              - "events",
            ] -> (known after apply)
          ~ source         = "DeviceMessages" -> (known after apply)
        }

      ~ sku {
          ~ capacity = 1 -> 10
          ~ name     = "S1" -> "S3"
        }

      - timeouts {}
    }
```

How can I prevent it to be replaced? What is the difference that is making Terraform think that it needs a new IoT Hub?

Comment: Have you changed basically everything about the `azurerm_iothub`, or is terraform incorrect as well in trying to change everything?

Comment: I've deleted all endpoints and routes to see if it helped. But I knew from before that deleting a route and an endpoint doesn't force recreation of the IoT Hub, it just modifies it.

Comment: I just hope for you that all the keys shown in your post are not valid anymore...

Comment: This seems to me like a bug in the UI layer of Terraform where it's not correctly annotating whatever attribute path(s) the provider returned as requiring replacement. Terraform Core makes the decision based on whether the provider returns any such paths _at all_, whereas it's the UI's responsibility to analyse the paths and determine what to add the annotation to.

Comment: If the UI isn't doing the right thing here then it might help to look "under the UI" at the raw data the UI is built from, by saving the plan to a file and then viewing the JSON version of it: `terraform plan -out=tfplan` followed by `terraform show -json tfplan`. That returns [a JSON serialization](https://www.terraform.io/internals/json-format#plan-representation) of the data that the UI would normally produce the diff from. Look for `replace_paths` properties in the JSON output.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I know it is not an answer, but after lots of trial and error, I've found that endpoints of type AzureIoTHub.StorageContainer force the recreation, while endpoints of EventHub do not. In theory, for both it shouldn't be required, an in fact, you can add them manually in the portal and then Terraform happily accepts it.